# Altera DE1 Board Read KEY?

Tags: vhdl

I need to press and hold key 1 and than press key 2 to increase value.
How to Read keys only if both keys are pressed. This is what is have which is not working correct. (programming languages vhdl).

if key(0) and key(1) are pessed do somthing

```
PORT (
KEY : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
);

SIGNAL A, B, C, D : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
A <= KEY(0) & KEY(1);
B <= KEY(0) & KEY(2);
C <= KEY(0) & KEY(3);

Readkey: process(KEY)
begin
if (A = 1) then
D <= "00";
if (B = 1) then
D <= "01";
if (C = 1) then
D <= "10";
end if;
end if;
end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surprised it's not working.  Now, I don't know the slightest thing about VHDL, but I do know about programming in general.

Firstly:  **INDENT YOUR CODE** With no indents the code is all but unreadable.  Here is your code indented properly:

```
PORT (
    KEY : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
);

SIGNAL A, B, C, D : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
    A <= KEY(0) & KEY(1);
    B <= KEY(0) & KEY(2);
    C <= KEY(0) & KEY(3);

Readkey: process(KEY) 
begin
    if (A = 1) then
        D <= "00";
        if (B = 1) then
            D <= "01";
            if (C = 1) then
                D <= "10";
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Now you can see one major flaw in your code at a glance.

C being 1 will only be tested if B is 1, which itself will only be tested if A is 1.  The `if` statements shouldn't be nested like that.

Secondly, (again, I don't know VHDL) is how A B and C are being assigned.  In a classic programming language you would need to assign the incoming values to A B and C every time you want to test them, otherwise you won't ever see any changes. This may not be the case in VHDL, but it's something to look more closely at.

Comment: In VHDL all code that's not controlled by a clock is a combinatorial assignment... you're describing a boolean logic equation implemented in hardware at that point. You can think of it as executing continously all the time.

Answer (score 2):

1) Fix the IF logic as Makjenko says.

2) "&" isn't the AND operator. It's combining elements into a vector. If KEY(0) and KEY(1) were both '1', you'd get an A value of "11", not 1.  In fact, that code shouldn't compile. Make A, B, and C **std_logic** instead of **std_logic_vector**, and assign them as:

```
A <= KEY(0) and KEY(1);
```

Then you can use:

```
if (A = '1') then
```

OR, leave as is and compare A with "11", etc.

3) What uses D?  If you had code like that with nothing using D...  the entire code section would be optimized away as not doing anything useful. Create an OUT signal in the port map, and assign D to it. Then, make sure to assign that to a pin somewhere.

4) I also don't think you have the right stuff in the sensitivity list. While it should be true that if KEY changes A,B, and C do...  I wouldn't trust a synthesis tool to do the right thing there.  Put (A,B,C) in the sensitivity list.

5) Make sure of the polarity of the KEY inputs. Can you get things to work if you only use one key press? A key press may be "0"... I know most of mine are.

Oh, and as Majenko says definitely indent your code.